# Name of a 90s animation about a boy and a whale?

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon, animation

There was an animated film in the 90s about a boy who took a shower and flooded the bathroom. When this happened he could swim through the pipes and meet a whale. Does anyone have any idea what the name of the movie was?